# How to create a tar file to a specific folder from a different folder

Tags: command-line, backup, tar

Hi guys i am new to linux.

I am trying to create a tar file from a different directory and want to be placed a specific directory.

I have tried this cmd

```
tar -cvf dailybackup.tar /root/filesfromlocalmachine/ -C /root/backup/
```

There is a folder in the name pf backup and i want the tar to be created there. But whenever i execute this the tar is been created at the folder where i am executing the command. Is there a way to create a tar file from a different folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, put the directory in front of the "tar".

```
cd /
tar -cvf /where/to/put/it/dailybackup.tar root/backup/
```

and it will backup `root/backup`.

I would suggest to always makes backups with a relative path (as I used in my answer) otherwise you might overwrite the destination when you wanted to restore it elsewhere and then do a compare with the backup version.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind,

can you tell how to exclude the parent directories which also being backuped. I want the files only to be backed up

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind,

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `tar` encounters a `-C` option, the current working directory changes, all subsequent options that follow are affected. It makes this option order-sensitive.

```
./a:      ./b:
file001   file002
```

e.g., using multiple `-C` options makes the second `-C` relative to the first.

```
$ tar -vcf archive.tar.gz -C ./a . -C ../b .  
./  
./file001  
./  
./file002
```

Because `-C` does not adjust the [FILE...] entry, *path expansion* (... globbing) will not work. However, in cases where globbing is required, `--transform` may be used.

```
$ tar -cvf archive.tar.gz \
    --show-transformed-names --transform='s:^./.*/::' ./[ab]/file00?
file001
file002
```

also, `'--strip-components=<n>'` can be used to strip leading components on extraction.

```
$ tar -vxf archive.tar.gz \
    --show-transformed-names --strip-components=2  
file001  
file002
```